# A question about the relativity of simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity

[image]

In the above figure Observer A is detecting the events P and Q by sending and receiving lights to the continuous paths. Observer B is also trying to locate the events by sending and receiving lights RQU and SPV respectively. My question is observer B would illuminate the events via other light rays; why s/he is taking the same light rays of observer A?

Answer (score 0):

The figure is a [Minkowski diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_diagram), where light rays always are lines with a 45 degrees slope. The diagram also shows only one space dimension. Wordlines of observers with different speeds are represented by differently inclined lines all passing through $O$.

Because of the above, the light reaching $P$ or $Q$ has to follow the 45 degrees line coming from downward, whatever event (observer) is its source; similarly, the light emitted from $P$ and $Q$, whatever observer it reaches, also must follow the single upward 45 degrees line.

Note that the relativity of simulaneity is illustrated by the upper part of the diagram, by considering at what times the light emitted from $P$ and $Q$ reaches both observers: for $A$, both light rays arrive at the same time. Since the spatial distances $OP$ and $OQ$ are the same, this means $P$ and $Q$ are simultaneous for $A$. On the other hand, for $B$ the light from $Q$ arrives first (at $U$), followed by the light from $P$ at $V$. Since again the spatial distances $OP$ and $OQ$ are the same for $B$* then it means that for $B$, $Q$ happens before $P$.

*It is not obvious from the diagram than spatial $OQ$ is the same than spatial $OP$ for $B$ (although that distance is not the same as for $A$!). To see this you would need to draw the tilted spatial $t=0$ for $B$, which is not horizontal but rises from left to right (see the diagram for a Lorentz boost in the Wikipedia page linked above).